Python-Poetry error on dependency propagation
Context:
I have several packages:
quickbio_books
quickbio
quickbio_frontend (base on Dash from plotly)

quickbio uses quickbio_books
# quickbio project.toml

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
# others libs

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
data-management-tools = {path = "../../data_management_tools", develop = true}
quickbio-books = {path = "../quickBio-books", develop = true}


quickbio_fronted uses quickbio
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
# others libs

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
quickbio = {path = "../quickBio", extras = ["dev"], develop = true}
data-management-tools = {path = "../../data_management_tools", extras = ["dev"], develop = true}
ft-utils = {path = "../ft_utils", extras = ["dev"], develop = true}
auth = {path = "../auth", extras = ["dev"], develop = true}


When i run quickbio_frontend it gives to me the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/reveur/python/environmental/quickBio-frontend/quickbio_frontend/app.py", line 14, in <module>
    from quickbio_frontend.src.pages.shell_props import appshell_props
  File "/home/reveur/python/environmental/quickBio-frontend/quickbio_frontend/src/pages/shell_props.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .diversity._shell_props import shell_props as diversity_shell_props
  File "/home/reveur/python/environmental/quickBio-frontend/quickbio_frontend/src/pages/diversity/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from quickbio.names.process import AllowAnalysis
  File "/home/reveur/python/environmental/quickBio/quickbio/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .process.search.country_book.country_book import CountryBook
  File "/home/reveur/python/environmental/quickBio/quickbio/process/search/country_book/country_book.py", line 6, in <module>
    import quickbio_books as qbio_books
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quickbio_books'

According to my understanding,
if I already have quickbio_book installed in quickbio,
and if I already have quickbio installed in quickbio_frontend,
isn't quickbio_book supposed to be available in quickbio_frontend already?
Note: I'm working on everything locally at the moment (dev mode)
Am I doing something wrong? Any solution to avoid having to install quickbio_books in quickbio_frontend?
all are installed as packages (poetry install)
I have used "extra dev" which is supposed to fix it as I understand it but it doesn't.

You misunderstand how Poetry works and what its "dev" dependencies are. poetry install does not do a regular installation, it installs the dev dependencies of the current project but of course it does not install the dev dependencies of the current project's dependencies. -- Maybe what you want to do, is to have develop and path on your regular dependencies, but it has a lot of shortcomings as well.
